# Need help finding a PHP e-Commerce package for virtual products/courses

Tags: php, e-commerce, lamp

Okay, I'm trying to figure out a good e-Commerce package for a client of mine, and it just isn't easy to find. I'm working on a LAMP system, so please try to restrict your software packages to that platform. (PHP 5 & MySQL 5 are easily available.)

*Don't mention Magento*, that was a nightmare to attempt to install and maintain.

---

I need an e-Commerce package that provides (required):

- **Quantity discounts.**

  For instance, a quantity of 1-4 is priced at $99 per unit, and 5-9 is priced at $89 per unit, etc.
- **Digital products.**

  My client wants to sell screencasts, podcasts, and e-Books; in other words: virtual products. Without support for virtual products, selling downloads is rather *difficult*.
- **Download protection.**

  Again, my client wants to sell downloads and wants to protect against hot-linking. The problem comes with adding in a quantity − selling seats to a screencast is pretty pointless without a modicum of control. Therefore, we need to limit downloads.

**What he'd actually like:**

My client wants to sell educational screencasts and podcasts, and would like to allow for a specific number of seats for a screencast or podcast. In addition, if possible he'd like to keep the screencast on the site and sell access to a number of them as a *training course*.

Obviously the course needs to expire, the individuals need to get access to the course, and the whole thing needs to be easy enough for someone with general web expertise to manage.

I'm running up against a wall here, folks. I've looked demos at OpenSourceCMS for so long I'm not even sure what to use. Is there a free or low cost ($100 - $400) package that will do what he *wants?*

If all else fails, what's easy enough to extend that I can add the functionality he needs?

Comment: You certainly won't find a (good) PHP web store that will do DRM protected video and audio broadcasting to a limited audience, which is basically what you want (if I understand correctly).

Comment: He doesn't want DRM, just course management.

Comment: I'm keen to hear the solution that you decided to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [OSCommerce](http://oscommerce.org/)?

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the suggestion, but yes I have and it doesn't fit the bill. OSCommerce doesn't allow for bulk discounts.